# Keep search on navbar when collapsed

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter

I'm trying to maintain a search bar on the right of my navbar when the menu is collapsed, but can't seem to get it just how I want it.

I want the search on the right for the full menu like this:
[image: full menu]

And for it to collapse looking like this:
[image: collapsed menu]

The best I can achieve has the search dialog wrapping to the next line and looks horrible.

Comment: You should share both your HTML and CSS code so people can help you with your problem. Check this on how to provide a good question with a good example: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve this, you'll need to take the `<form>` out of `.navbar-collapse` and use `@media` queries to position the search box where you want.

```css
@media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 899px) {
  .navbar-search {
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 100px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 900px) {
  .navbar-search {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 40px;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    <!-- Search form goes here out side of .navbar-collapse -->
    <form class="navbar-form navbar-search">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default hidden-xs hidden-sm">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>

  <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Here's a working codepen example for you to review. http://codepen.io/yongchuc/pen/dpxeEg